# Is it possible to convert copied text in excel to plain text?

Tags: microsoft-excel

if I already have lots of copied content in a sheet, is it possible to convert all of it to plain text without copying and pasting it again?

Comment: Copypaste using intermediate storage (notepad for example). Ctrl-C (in Excel) -> Ctrl-V, Ctrl-A, Ctrl-X (in notepad) -> Ctrl-V (in Excel).

Comment: I think copy them to Text Document is the simplest way. Or do you want to save the Excel file as a text file?

Comment: Define converting to plain text. You could select all, go to format, cell format, and pick "Normal". This will remove any formatting, including things like dates.

Comment: If the copied data has color/font/ or any format applied & want to convert them into NON Formatted /Plain text then use COPY,,,, Paste Special,,, select VALUE ,, in case you want to apply this on entire sheet/workbook then better use Macro.

Answer (score 0):

Use save as to save as a CSV file which is 100% text.